# Android game 3 trials for user

Tags: java, android

Hello it's my first time to develop android color game. However I'd like to put 3 trials in each question. I'm a bit confused how or where to put my while loop in my code. Please have a look on what I have tried so far:

```
  int trial = 0;

  private void getCorrectObject() {

    List<Integer> objects = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    objects.add(1);
    objects.add(2);
    objects.add(3);
    objects.add(4);
    objects.add(5);
    objects.add(6);
    objects.add(7);
    objects.add(8);
    objects.add(9);

    Collections.shuffle(objects);
    int correctObject =  objects.get(0);
    Log.d("test", String.valueOf(correctObject));



    while(trial <=3){
        trial++;


    switch(correctObject)
    {
    case 1:
        bObjectCorrect.setImageResource(R.drawable.stage1_1_object1);
        bObjectCorrect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Stage1_2.class);
                startActivity(i);
                new Thread(){
                    public void run(){
                        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(Stage1_2.this, R.raw.brown);
                        mp.start();
                    }
                }.start();
                finish();
            }
        });
        break;
    case 2:
        bObject1.setImageResource(R.drawable.stage1_1_object1);
        bObject1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Stage1_2.class);
                startActivity(i);
                new Thread(){
                    public void run(){
                        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(Stage1_2.this, R.raw.brown);
                        mp.start();
                    }
                }.start();
                finish();
            }
        });
        break;
    case 3:
        bObject2.setImageResource(R.drawable.stage1_1_object1);
        bObject2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Stage1_2.class);
                startActivity(i);
                new Thread(){
                    public void run(){
                        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(Stage1_2.this, R.raw.brown);
                        mp.start();
                    }
                }.start();
                finish();
            }
        });
        break;
    case 4:
        bObject3.setImageResource(R.drawable.stage1_1_object1);
        bObject3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Stage1_2.class);
                startActivity(i);
                new Thread(){
                    public void run(){
                        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(Stage1_2.this, R.raw.brown);
                        mp.start();
                    }
                }.start();
                finish();
            }
        });
        break;
    case 5:
        bObject4.setImageResource(R.drawable.stage1_1_object1);
        bObject4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Stage1_2.class);
                startActivity(i);
                new Thread(){
                    public void run(){
                        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(Stage1_2.this, R.raw.brown);
                        mp.start();
                    }
                }.start();
                finish();
            }
        });
        break;
    case 6:
        bObject5.setImageResource(R.drawable.stage1_1_object1);
        bObject5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Stage1_2.class);
                startActivity(i);
                new Thread(){
                    public void run(){
                        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(Stage1_2.this, R.raw.brown);
                        mp.start();
                    }
                }.start();
                finish();
            }
        });
        break;
    case 7:
        bObject6.setImageResource(R.drawable.stage1_1_object1);
        bObject6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Stage1_2.class);
                startActivity(i);
                new Thread(){
                    public void run(){
                        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(Stage1_2.this, R.raw.brown);
                        mp.start();
                    }
                }.start();
                finish();
            }
        });
        break;
    case 8:
        bObject7.setImageResource(R.drawable.stage1_1_object1);
        bObject7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Stage1_2.class);
                startActivity(i);
                new Thread(){
                    public void run(){
                        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(Stage1_2.this, R.raw.brown);
                        mp.start();
                    }
                }.start();
                finish();
            }
        });
        break;
    case 9:
        bObject8.setImageResource(R.drawable.stage1_1_object1);
        bObject8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Stage1_2.class);
                startActivity(i);
                new Thread(){
                    public void run(){
                        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(Stage1_2.this, R.raw.brown);
                        mp.start();
                    }
                }.start();
                finish();
            }
        });
        break;
    } // Last of switch statement


    if(trial == 3){
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Game Over")
        .setMessage("Sorry you reached your 3rd trial")
        .setPositiveButton("Try Again?", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                Intent i = new Intent(Stage1_2.this, Stage1_1.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
         })
        .setNegativeButton("Back to Menu", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                Intent i = new Intent(Stage1_2.this, ShapingColors.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
         })
         .show();
    }

    } // end of while loop
```

I really like to finish this thing so I can continue with the game. Any help is truly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

I added a new method called **guessedWrong()**

```
 private void guessedWrong(){
    trial++;

    if(trial == 3){
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Game Over")
        .setMessage("Sorry you reached your 3rd trial")
        .setPositiveButton("Try Again?", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                Intent i = new Intent(Stage1_1.this, Stage1_1.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
         })
        .setNegativeButton("Back to Menu", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                Intent i = new Intent(Stage1_1.this, ShapingColors.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
         })
         .show();
    }


}
```

Comment: set `trial` as a field

Comment: I'm sorry there was a mistake in my code. I already set it as field.

Comment: I don't fully understand your question because it seems to me that the "while" sentence is correct at that place, but as far as I see you should read the value for "correctObject" inside the loop (otherwise it will have always the same value) and the condition should be (trial < 3) otherwise it will iterate four times (trial = 0, trial = 1, trial = 2, trial = 3)

Comment: Edit from my previous comment: put "Collections.shuffle(objects);" and "correctObject =  objects.get(0);" inside the while loop

Comment: if you explain what the user is supposed to do then we can help you, it's not very clear what's happening between each trial. What's the outcome you're getting, and why is that wrong?

Comment: @Eluvatar the user will choose from random choices, user has only 3 trials to guess the correct answer.

Comment: @maxivis it's based on user's click..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you're confused is that you can't use a loop for this task. When using the Java Android framework, each of your callback functions (for example, an `onClick` listener, or your `Activity`'s `onResume`) has to run and finish within one frame of the application. Only after the function returns does your app update the screen. This means that if you're doing something like responding to a series of clicks, you can't do that in a loop. You have to handle each click in a separate call to the callback. `for` and `while` loops are appropriate if you want to iterate over a list of items to decide what should happen *right now* (for example, if you're adding items to a `ListView`), but you can't iterate over things that happen at different times (such as the user's guesses).

You have to think about your `Activity` like a state machine. Make `trial` a member variable (field) of the `Activity`, which starts out at `0`. You might have a function `guessedWrong()` which increments `trial`, and goes to the "game over" screen if it's greater than 2. The `onClick` listener for the wrong answers will call this function. When moving to a new question, reset `trial` to `0`.

You also need to make sure the number of trials (which state you're in) is preserved if your `Activity` is restarted. The lesson [Recreating an Activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html) in the [Android Developers' Training](https://developer.android.com/training/index.html) offered by Google shows you how to do this.

Comment: Thanks for this, after creating my own guessedWrong() method, how do I know the wrong answers since I shuffled them?

Comment: After picking a right answer, save it in a field too so you can get it later. Alternatively, you could call `setTag` on the right button, and you can later check whether the clicked button has the tag you set.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't get what you mean here, so what you're trying to say is am gonna do something like this: bObject6.setTag(); what will I put inside it? correctObject variable?

Comment: You can put anything you like in it.